# Looking for an introductory text to quantum physics

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

I'm looking for an introductory but mathematically rigorous introduction to quantum physics. Ideally, it would be written for someone with a great deal of mathematical sophistication but no great exposure to anything but the most elementary parts of physics (e.g. what might be obtained from an undergraduate course in classical mechanics).

I've always been curious about the subject (seems to be one of the great monuments to the human mind), but the textbooks I've found are either insultingly elementary or presuppose a greater familiarity with physics at large than I possess.

Comment: What books you already saw? The _Griffths Volumes_  and _Liboff_ or _Gasiorowicz_?

Comment: You can also see this [question 1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/635060/mathematical-and-theoretical-physics-books?rq=1) and [question 2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/758502/mathematics-needed-in-the-study-of-quantum-physics?rq=1) that you may like, seems that this is what youre asking for

Comment: Quantum Mathematical Physics by Walter Thirring

Comment: I liked Brian C. Hall's book: https://www.amazon.com/Quantum-Theory-Mathematicians-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/146147115X/ref=asap_bc?ie=UTF8